# Python - Recursively calling __str__() only returns one item

Tags: python

This is my code (pretty simple)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        node = self
        if node.next:
            node = node.next
            return node.__str__()
        return str(self.data)
```

Now, when I create two Nodes, like so:

```
a = Node(1,1)
b = Node(2,a)
print(b)
```

it returns

```
1
```

My question is, when I do print(b), shouldn't it print

```
2
1
```

? Because first, it will check if node.next exists (in this case, it does. node.next is a). It will then do

```
    node = node.next
    return node.__str__() # a.__str__() which is equal to 1
return str(self.data) # this correctly returns 2
```

How come it doesn't return

```
2
1
```

and returns only

```
1
```

instead?

Comment: Why would you expect it to return `2` followed by `1`? There's nothing in the code that would do that.

Comment: @kindall I mentioned my thought process in my post. Assume a=Node(1,1) and b=Node(2,a). When I do print(b), return str(self.data) should return 2. But that's not all, because in my __str__(), I also have "if node.next: node=node.next return node.__str__() # return a.__str__(), which should return 1... right? Currently, my code just returns 1.

Comment: `return` ends a function call; a call that hits the first `return` won't continue on to the second.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use `if OBJECT...` to check whether or not it exists...?

Comment: @JamesSmith hm, I'm using Python3.4.0 and I just opened up an interactive shell and did "testVar = None" "if testVar: print("exists") else: print("does not exist")" and it prints "does not exist". I did the same test with my Node. I did "node = Node("data")" "if node: print("node exists")" and it printed "node exists". Then I did "if node.next: print("exists")" and it did not print anything. Lastly, I tried "if not node.next: print("does not exist")" and it printed "does not exist". So my conclusion is that "if OBJECT" does check whether or not it exists, right?

Comment: @user2719875 Oh! That's cool. I'm just checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not concatenate values. It seems to just recurse until it hits the end, then return (only) this value. A...

```
return node.__str__() + str(self.data)
```

...might be more along the lines of what you wanted.

Comment: hm, from my understanding, shouldn't "return str(self.data)" return 2, and "return node.__str__()" return 1 (Assuming a=Node(1,1) and b=Node(2,a) and I called print(b)?

Comment: Yes, but the code should terminate at the return. After each return, the calling function resumes, only to return what it got - no more. There is nothing in there that concatenates values.

Comment: @ChristophSummer Ah, okay got it. Thanks. Just an FYI though, "return node.str() + str(self.data)" gives an "AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'str'". I changed node.str() to node.__str__() and it worked.

Comment: I apologize - markdown converted the underscores to boldface. I will edit the code to fix this.